# Apache Web Server ETag Header Information Disclosure Weakness

Tags: apache, kali-linux, ubuntu, web, ctf

How this vulnerability allow remote attackers to obtain  sensitive information likes inode number and child process though ETag header ? and how to locate path to a file from inode number ?